# How does "-refresh=false" flag work with terraform apply?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

So there's a [doc](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/run/modes-and-options#skipping-automatic-state-refresh) that says

> The `-refresh=false` option is used in normal planning mode to skip the default behavior of refreshing Terraform state before checking for configuration changes.

```
CLI: Use terraform plan -refresh=false or terraform apply -refresh=false.
```

My `foo` resource has `password` attribute that is required for a successful `GET /id` (which I know is a little bit of an anti-pattern but it is what it is). What I'd like to do is to test a "disaster recovery" (how to rotate a password if someone deletes it outside of TF but `password` is still present in TF state -- to avoid 401 error).

For example,

```
resource "foo" "bar" {
   ...
   password = "123"
}
```

And let's assume someone deleted `123` as a possible password option so I update a config to

```
resource "foo" "bar" {
   ...
   password = "456"
}
```

Now when I run `terraform plan -target="foo.bar"` I get `401` error. However when I run `terraform plan -refresh=false -target="foo.bar"` it works expected:

```
 ~ resource "foo" "bar" {
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ password    = (sensitive value)

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

so everything looks great.

However when I run `terraform apply -refresh=false -target="foo.bar"` I still get the same `401` error. Are there any hidden `read` calls or something? `fooUpdate` code is pretty much empty and doesn't call remote API.

**Update**: I managed to avoid the errors by running:

```
$ terraform plan -refresh=false -target="foo.bar" -out=my.plan
$ terraform apply my.plan
```

I'm still a little bit confused why it works but

```
$ terraform plan -refresh=false -target="foo.bar"
$ terraform apply -refresh=false -target="foo.bar"
```

doesn't.

Comment: All of the requests and error messages you are describing are being made by whatever provider this resource belongs to rather than by Terraform Core directly, and so unfortunately it's not possible to answer without knowing which specific provider and resource types you are using.